# .Bat to remove columns or remove text in a csv file

Tags: batch-file, csv

I have created the below .bat file to look at what programs are installed on their PC.

```
cd C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /s | findstr /B ".*DisplayName" >%USERNAME%.CSV
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /s | findstr /B ".*DisplayName" >>%USERNAME%.CSV
```

However on the output I only want the name of the program to be shown. At the moment the output is:

```
DisplayName    REG_SZ    Microsoft Office Excel MUI (English) 2010
```

I want to somehow have my output as just “Microsoft Office Excel MUI (English) 2010” So remove the “    DisplayName    REG_SZ    “ All the rows of data contain the word “REG_SZ”.

Any help would be great.

Thank you

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
@echo off
cd C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents
type nul > %USERNAME%.CSV
for /f "tokens=1,2*" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /s ^| findstr /B ".*DisplayName"') do (
    echo %%c >> %USERNAME%.CSV
)
for /f "tokens=1,2*" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /s ^| findstr /B ".*DisplayName"') do (
    echo %%c >> %USERNAME%.CSV
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need to do is replace the string 'DisplayName REG_SZ' with an empty string '', everywhere in your output.  You can do that in a batch file using string replacement, like so:

```
set string=%string:DisplayName REG_SZ.=%
```

Comment: Do I just add this line to the bottom of my bach file, sorry new to all of this so just learning.